# Should I use atomic integer or sync

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, synchronization, atomic

I've got a little confused about using atomic/volatile/sync in my code.
Let's say I have an object of book info in a bookstore and for example, it may happen that two threads want to take the same book while the amount in the inventory is only 1, how can I promise that only one thread will take the book?
do I have to use synchronize?
BookInventoryInfo:

```
package bgu.spl.mics.application.passiveObjects;

import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicInteger;

/**
 * Passive data-object representing a information about a certain book in the inventory.
 * 
 * <p>
 *
 */
public class BookInventoryInfo {

    //The title of the book, his amount in the inventory and the price
    private String bookTitle;
    private AtomicInteger amountInInventory;
    private int price;

    public BookInventoryInfo(String bookTitle, int amountInInventory, int price) {
        this.bookTitle = bookTitle;
        this.price = price;
        this.amountInInventory = new AtomicInteger(amountInInventory);
    }


    /**
     * Retrieves the title of this book.
     * <p>
     * @return The title of this book.   
     */
    public String getBookTitle() {
        return this.bookTitle;
    }

    /**
     * Retrieves the amount of books of this type in the inventory.
     * <p>
     * @return amount of available books.      
     */
    public int getAmountInInventory() {
        return this.amountInInventory.get();
    }

    /**
     * Retrieves the price for  book.
     * <p>
     * @return the price of the book.
     */
    public int getPrice() {
        return this.price;
    }

    public void reduceAmountInInventory() {
        this.amountInInventory.decrementAndGet();
    }
}
```

The way I want to take the book:

```
if(book.getAmountInInventory > 0)
{
    book.amountInInventory--
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use `synchronized` as using AtomicInteger isn't as simple as it might appear at first glance. While individual operations on AtomicInteger are thread safe, using multiple operations might not be.  Your example is a good one. say you have

```
// say it start at 1
Thread1: if(book.getAmountInInventory > 0)
Thread2: if(book.getAmountInInventory > 0)
Thread1: book.amountInInventory--
Thread2: book.amountInInventory--
```

The amount is now -1.

If you use `synchronized` it is much simpler to hold the lock for the whole operation

```
synchronized (book) {
    if(book.getAmountInInventory > 0) // no chance for a race condition here.
    {
        book.amountInInventory--
    }
```

Comment: Thank you, so with synchronize I dont need to worry about the possibility that the int value will be updated only at the cache and not in the ram?

Answer (score 3):

An `AtomicInteger` isn't sufficient here. While it would allow you to decrement the number of copies in the inventory atomically, that isn't enough - you don't need to just decrement it atomically, you also need to add some custom logic.

I'd use a plain old `int`, and protect its modification with explicit `synchronized` blocks or methods:

```
public class BookInventoryInfo {

    private String bookTitle;
    private int amountInInventory;
    private int price;

    public synchronized void checkOut() {
        if (amountInInventory <= 0) {
            throw new BookCheckoutException("No book in inventory");
        }
        amountInInventory--;
    }

    // All the other methods...
}
```

Answer (score 3):

As an alternative to synchronization, you can also use a [`compareAndSet`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicInteger.html#compareAndSet-int-int-):

```
int a = book.amountInventory.get();
if (a > 0) {
  boolean updated = book.amountInInventory.compareAndSet(a, a - 1);
}
```

This will *only* decrement the value of `amountInInventory` if its value is still `a` when you come to update it. The return value of `compareAndSet` indicates whether the value was changed or not.

You can wrap this in a loop, something like:

```
while (true) {
  int a = book.amountInventory.get();
  if (a == 0) {
    return false;  // To mean "no book in inventory";
  }
  if (book.amountInInventory.compareAndSet(a, a - 1)) {
    return true;  // To mean "there was a book in inventory, and it was removed".
  }
}
```